# How to make tab key shift test after cursor in evil mode insert state

Tags: key-bindings, indentation, evil

To be honest, I'm very novice in Emacs, so is it possible somehow to bind TAB key in **insert** state of *evil mode* to shift text after the cursor right on current indentation amount of spaces at each key press. And how to do reverse process (shifting of  text after cursor to the left) on Shift+TAB pressing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vim, one would use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> in insert mode for this, which is replicated in Evil.

That being said, you would have to [rebind](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil#toc8) functions `evil-shift-left-line` and `evil-shift-right-line` to <kbd>TAB</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>.

Comment: This is great, thank you very much!!